# Prove by induction that every integer is either a prime or product of primes

Tags: elementary-number-theory, induction

Let $n$ and $d$ be integers such that $d$ is a divisor of $n$ if $n=ad$ for some integer $a$. A prime number is a integer $n>1$ that is divisible by 1 and itself. Prove by induction that every integer $n>1$ is either a prime or product of primes.

**My attempt:**

Proving equation is true for a particular $n$

If $n=2$ then $n=2=2\cdot 1=1\cdot 2=ad$ , $d$=1,2 then $n$ its a prime since a prime is greater than 1.

If $n=4$ them $n=4=2\cdot 2\cdot 1=1\cdot 2\cdot 2=ad$ , $d$=1,2  then its a product of primes namely $n=2\cdot 2$.

is this ok ?

now assuming $n$ is true lets prove $n+1$

$n=ad$

$n+1=ad+1$

If its prime  then...

If it is a product of primes then...

I don't know how to continue

I have seen [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/833746/complete-induction-proof-that-every-n-1-can-be-written-as-a-product-of-prime) however i don't know if it is a good answer however I find it incomplete

Comment: Try to complete the answer you have cited [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/833746/complete-induction-proof-that-every-n-1-can-be-written-as-a-product-of-prime).

Comment: see here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic

Comment: This sentence "if $n=2$ then $n=2=2\cdot 1=1\cdot 2=ad$ , $d$=1,2 them $n$ its a prime since a prime is greatter than 1" is very bad English.  First off, I noticed you wrote "them" every time you meant "then" (I fixed most of them).  You should take your time and formulate your sentences carefully.

Comment: yes , i have make some mistakes

Comment: how i complete the answer by editing the answer there? @DietrichBurde

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need strong induction, so you assume it holds for all $n < N$.

Then you prove it for $n=N$.

---

For $n=2$ it clearly holds.

Now assume it holds for all $n < N$.

If $N$ is a prime, then the statement is true.

Else, you can write $N = a\cdot b$ with $a,b < N$, and by the strong induction hypothesis you can write $a,b$ as a prime or a product of primes, so $N$ is a product of primes.

Comment: is in  my attempt  the prove that n=2 holds ok?

Comment: No, not really, you can just say that n=2 is prime and be done with it.

Comment: strong induction is when using inequalities?

Comment: I don't really understand the question, but strong induction is used when you not only assume the previous value, but all previous values.

Comment: ok now i understand what you mean by strong induction, thanks